ros2 delta_joint_cmds error
roxstarstephen@lp:~$ ros2 interface show control_msgs/msg/JointJog
# Used in time-stamping the message.
std_msgs/Header header
    builtin_interfaces/Time stamp
        int32 sec
        uint32 nanosec
    string frame_id

# Name list of the joints. You don't need to specify all joints of the
# robot. Joint names are case-sensitive.
string[] joint_names

# A position command to the joints listed in joint_names.
# The order must be identical.
# Units are meters or radians.
# If displacements and velocities are filled, a profiled motion is requested.
float64[] displacements # or position_deltas

# A velocity command to the joints listed in joint_names.
# The order must be identical.
# Units are m/s or rad/s.
# If displacements and velocities are filled, a profiled motion is requested.
float64[] velocities

float64 duration
roxstarstephen@lp:~$ ros2 topic pub /delta_joint_cmd control_msgs/msg/JointJog "header:
  stamp:
    sec: 0
    nanosec: 0
  frame_id: 'base_link'
joint_names: ['elbow_joint', 'wrist_1_joint']
displacements: [0.1, -0.05]
velocities: [0.0, 0.0]
duration: 1.0" -r 125
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.18.11', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 91, in main
    rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2topic/command/topic.py", line 41, in main
    return extension.main(args=args)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2topic/verb/pub.py", line 222, in main
    return main(args)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2topic/verb/pub.py", line 240, in main
    return publisher(
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2topic/verb/pub.py", line 271, in publisher
    values_dictionary = yaml.safe_load(values)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 162, in safe_load
    return load(stream, SafeLoader)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 114, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 173, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_stream_end()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 377, in fetch_stream_end
    self.remove_possible_simple_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 318, in remove_possible_simple_key
    raise ScannerError("while scanning a simple key", key.mark,
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "<unicode string>", line 9, column 1:
    duration: 1.0 -r 125
    ^
could not find expected ':'
  in "<unicode string>", line 9, column 21:
    duration: 1.0 -r 125
                        ^
roxstarstephen@lp:~$ ros2 topic pub /delta_joint_cmd control_msgs/msg/JointJog "header:
  stamp:
    sec: 0
    nanosec: 0
  frame_id: 'base_link'
joint_names: ['elbow_joint', 'wrist_1_joint']
displacements: [0.1, -0.05]
velocities: [0.0, 0.0]
duration: 1.0" -r 125:
Failed to populate field: 'JointJog' object has no attribute 'duration: 1.0 -r 125'

